# How does "Android CI" GitHub Action work without setting up Android tools?

Tags: android, github, github-actions

"Android CI" is a workflow provided by GitHub itself to build Android projects using GitHub Actions. Looking at the workflow file, it does not set up any Android tools like SDK or command line tools, environment variables, etc. which are needed to build an Android project. The runner is an `ubuntu-latest` runner. How is the runner about to build an Android project without the required dependencies?

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#android